# How do I upload a file to Azurite from terminal?

Tags: bash, azure, terminal, azure-cli

I'm using Azurite and wish to create a container/upload a blob etc from the bash terminal!

I've tried using the Azure CLI like this::

```
az storage container create --account-name devstoreaccount1 --account-key Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw== --name mycontainer
```

But of course it doesn't work and complains of Authentication failure! By the way the correct account key and name are used in that example.

I believe it's not possible to talk to Azurite using the Azure CLI.

All I want to do is create a container and upload a file to it from the terminal.

Does anybody know if this is possible? Or will I have to use a Java client (for example) to do the job?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to my test, when we account key and account name with Azure CLI to create blob container, cli will use `https` protocol to connect Azurite. But, in default, Azurite just support `http` protocol. For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azurite)
[image]

So I suggest you use connection string to connect Azurite with Azure CLI, the connection string will tell Azure CLI uses `http` protocol.

For example

1. Create contanier

```
az storage container create -n test --connection-string "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;"
```

[image]

2. Upload file

```
az storage blob upload -f D:\test.csv -c test -n test.csv --connection-string "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;"
```

[image]

Comment: This works! I tried to do the same thing using Https, and it fails with this error:

Max retries exceeded with url: /devstoreaccount1/identity?restype=container (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)).
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=10000):


Any pointers?

Comment: @Ayushmati If you want to use HTTPS, please refer to https://github.com/Azure/Azurite#https-setup

Comment: I have followed all the steps and I can view my storage account in AzureStorageExplorer. But when I try to add a blobcontainer using the commands above, it throws the error.